# Why can't I see all the assignments on Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

I have most of the assignments completed but I can't see the AUG or Scar-L and I need those guns.

Also are the assignments supposed to disappear when they are completed or just stay there?

Comment: Do you see the other CQC assignments? And no they don't disappear in battlelog or in game.

Comment: You can't see the guns? Or the assignments to unlock them?

Comment: Do you own premium or only some of the DLCs?

Answer (score 1):

Completing "`most of the assignments`" doesn't automatically grand you access to AUG and/or SCAR-L. You have to unlock them by completing [`SHEPARD`](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Shepard) and [`SET US UP THE BOMB`](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Set_Us_Up_The_Bomb) assignments of `Close Quarters` DLC.

No, assignments do not disappear once you complete them, they all stay at your `Assignments` page @Battlelog. If you see a just a gray [`3`](http://battlelog-cdn.battlefield.com/cdnprefix/14d47a6313f99/public/profile/bf3/assignments/16384/a00.jpg) instead of a blue-ish picture, you have to unlock some other assignments before getting access to the closed one.

Answer (score 0):

The assignments stay there. Since End Game, I noticed that EA (or DICE) destroyed the assignment page CSS again. Maybe it's a temporary bug. There are no way to search for them (ctrl+f does not work sadly).